# How to add/display an attribute for a Simple Product on Checkout Page?

Tags: php, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to display the Attribute "marke" from a Single Product on Checkout Page but all I get to see is "Array".

```
<?php $product_attributes = get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'], '_product_attributes', true); $product_attributes['marke']['value']; ?>
```

This Code i paste below `<?php echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>`

I know its stupid but I'm realy new in php/wocommerce, would be nice if someone could say me what I'm doing wrong there, or what could I change?

---

Woocommerce Ver. 2.3.7

Comment: use print_r() instead of echo, it will show you the array contents, you can then use that to echo out the proper value from within the array

Comment: You mean at this part <?php print_r()$product_attributes... or? I would be realy thankfull if u could go more into details...Thanks!

Comment: sorry to take so long, had a bug.  yeah, wherever you are echoing  that is getting you "Array" use var_dump or print_r instead.